# rebar release is not starting with strange errors

Tags: erlang, release, erlang-otp, rebar

When doing 'rebar generate' under MacOS things running just fine. When doing the same under linux (gentoo), starting release fails, with error related to asn1_db. Does it mean erlang installation on host system is broken in some sense?

```
Exec: /home/apis/smsapi/rel/smsapi/erts-5.9/bin/erlexec -boot /home/apis/smsapi/rel/smsapi/releases/1/smsapi -mode embedded -config /home/apis/smsapi/rel/smsapi/releases/1/sys.config -args_file /home/apis/smsapi/rel/smsapi/releases/1/vm.args -- console 
Root: /home/apis/smsapi/rel/smsapi
{"init terminating in do_boot",{'cannot load',asn1_db,get_file}}

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()
```

Answer (score 0):

Rebar cannot find the `asn1_db` module, which is part of the `asn1` Erlang application. Some distributions have a separate package for this application, named `erlang-asn1`. Maybe that's the case for Gentoo?

You can try and add the following to your `reltool.config`:

```
{app, asn1, [{incl_cond, exclude}]}
```

This will exclude the application from the release.